# Is there any way to fix this loop in VBA Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have few sheets in my Excel. I want this code to apply Some specific Sheet. Since I am not good at vba I am unable to do it. Please somebody help me. How do I add Sheet3 to 17 to this code so that code only run for these sheets.

```vb
Sub insertRowsSheets()
    ' Disable Excel properties before macro runs
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    
    ' Declare object variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet, iCountRows As Integer
    Dim activeSheet As Worksheet, activeRow As Long
    Dim startSheet As String
        
  ' State activeRow
    activeRow = ActiveCell.Row
    
 ' Save initial active sheet selection
    startSheet = ThisWorkbook.activeSheet.Name
               
    ' Trigger input message to appear - in terms of how many rows to insert
    iCountRows = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="How many rows do you want to insert, starting with row " _
    & activeRow & "?", Type:=1)
        
    ' Error handling - end the macro if a zero, negative integer or non-integer value is entered
    If iCountRows = False Or iCountRows <= 0 Then End
    
    ' Loop through the worksheets in active workbook
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        ws.Activate
        Rows(activeRow & ":" & activeRow + iCountRows - 1).Insert
        Range("A9").Select
        Range("A8:C8").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("A9").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Range("D8:J8").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D8:J9")
        Range("D8:J9").Select
        Range("K8:L8").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("K9").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Range("M8:T8").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M8:T9")
        Range("M8:T9").Select
        Range("A8").Select
    Next ws
                            
    ' Move cursor back to intial worksheet
    Worksheets(startSheet).Select
    Range("A8").Select
                   
    ' Re-enable Excel properties once macro is complete
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With                                     
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this all happening in one workbook i.e. `ActiveWorkbook` i.e. `ThisWorkbook`? If not, please do clarify.

Comment: Yes. all of my sheets are in one workbook.

Comment: This code works fine. But there are 6 sheet that i don't want this code to be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update Worksheets

- This should work the same way as before.
- At least it should help you to figure out how to loop through an array of worksheet names instead of the worksheets collection.
- I could not figure out the logic of copying and filling. Shouldn't you be filling as many rows as the user selected starting from the active row?

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub insertRowsSheets()
    
    ' Define Worksheet Names Array.
    Dim wsNames As Variant ' Tab names, not code names.
    wsNames = Array("Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", "Sheet6", "Sheet7", _
                    "Sheet8", "Sheet9", "Sheet10", "Sheet11", "Sheet12", _
                    "Sheet13", "Sheet14", "Sheet15", "Sheet16", "Sheet17")
    
    ' Declare object variables
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Dim RowsCount As Long
    Dim ActiveRow As Long
    Dim StartSheet As String
    Dim i As Long
        
    ' Define workbook.
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    
    ' State activeRow
    ActiveRow = ActiveCell.Row
    
    ' Trigger input message to appear - in terms of how many rows to insert
    RowsCount = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="How many rows do you want to insert, starting with row " _
    & ActiveRow & "?", Type:=1)
        
    ' Error handling - end the macro if a zero, negative integer or non-integer value is entered
    If RowsCount = False Or RowsCount <= 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Loop through the worksheets.
    For i = LBound(wsNames) To UBound(wsNames)
        With wb.Worksheets(wsNames(i))
            .Rows(ActiveRow & ":" & ActiveRow + RowsCount - 1).Insert
            .Range("A9:C9").Value = .Range("A8:C8").Value
            .Range("D8:J8").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("D8:J9")
            .Range("K9:L9").Value = .Range("K8:L8").Value
            .Range("M8:T8").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("M8:T9")
        End With
    Next i
                   
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me check and i will let you know.

Comment: I am getting a runtime error 9, Subscript out of range

Comment: FIlling is not necessary but copy data from a8 to a9 because A8, B8 and K8, L8 have a vlookup code, And everyweek A8 Get new data from a websource. and A8 to T8 is all i need to copy down as values

Comment: This is working like magic. Thank You so much for helping me

Answer (score 0):

```
' Loop through the worksheets in active workbook
For i = 3 To 17 Step 1 'This runs from the 3rd Sheet to the 17th irrespective of the name. Use array method if the sheets are mixed up
    If WorksheetIDExists(i, ActiveWorkbook) Then
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
        With ws
            .Rows(activeRow & ":" & activeRow + iCountRows - 1).Insert '<- Kindly note that, if the active row is above A8, the whole script becomes a mess
            .Range("A8:C8").Copy
            .Range("A9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            .Range("D8:J9").FillDown
            .Range("K8:L8").Copy
            .Range("K9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            .Range("M8:T8").FillDown
            .Range("A8").Select
        End With
    End If
Next i
```

Add this Function as well.

```
Function WorksheetIDExists(shtid As Integer, wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = wb.Worksheets(shtid)
    On Error GoTo 0
    WorksheetIDExists = Not sht Is Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Hey thank you for trying to help me. Problem is solved already